# How to remove html from exported order csv?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have added item quantity with product SKU in order grid. I have an option to load more or load less if the items more than 3 in a single order. Item quantity is displaying fine in the order grid. But when I export the order CSV, the load more or load less html code is displaying in the order csv. How can I prevent the html for the order csv.

I am using below code for SKU with item quantity:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    /** @var MageWorx_OrdersGrid_Helper_Data $helper */
    $helper = Mage::helper('mageworx_ordersgrid');

    $orderitemqty = array();
    $$orderitemsku = array();
    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($row['increment_id']);//increment_id,like 100000004
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach($ordered_items as $item){
      $orderitemqty[] = $item->getSku(). ' (' .floor($item->getQtyOrdered()).')';
    } 


    $prCount = count($orderitemqty);
    if ($prCount > 3) {
        $orderitemqty[$prCount - 1] .= '<a href="" onclick="$(\'hdiv_' . $row->getData('increment_id') . '_' . $prefix . '\').style.display=\'none\'; $(\'a_' . $row->getData('increment_id') . '_' . $prefix . '\').style.display=\'block\'; return false;" style="float:right; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: none;" title="' . $helper->__('Less..') . '">↑</a>'
            . '</div>'
            . '<a href="" id="a_' . $row->getData('increment_id') . '_' . $prefix . '" onclick="$(\'hdiv_' . $row->getData('increment_id') . '_' . $prefix . '\').style.display=\'block\'; this.style.display=\'none\'; return false;" style="float:right; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: none;" title="' . $helper->__('More..') . '">↓</a>';
        $orderitemqty[2] .= '<div id="hdiv_' . $row->getData('increment_id') . '_' . $prefix . '" style="display:none">' . $orderitemqty[3];

        unset($orderitemqty[3]);
    }

    $data = implode('<br/>', $orderitemqty);        
    if (strpos(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestString(), '/exportCsv/')) {
        $data = str_replace(array('&nbsp;','<br/>'), array(' ','|'), $data);
    }
    return $data; 
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can escape HTML tags by overriding the `_prepareDownloadResponse()` controller function. This function declares headers and content file in response for file download.

To do so, you have to first rewrite/override the `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController` controller class same as below.

> app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

    ...

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Namespace_Module_Adminhtml</Namespace_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    ...

</config>
```

> app/code/local/Namespace/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php

```
<?php

    require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php";

    class Namespace_Module_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
    {
        /**
         * Declare headers and content file in response for file download
         *
         * @param string $fileName
         * @param string|array $content set to null to avoid starting output, $contentLength should be set explicitly in
         *                              that case
         * @param string $contentType
         * @param int $contentLength    explicit content length, if strlen($content) isn't applicable
         * @return Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
         */
        protected function _prepareDownloadResponse(
            $fileName,
            $content,
            $contentType = 'application/octet-stream',
            $contentLength = null)
        {

            ...

            if (!is_null($content)) {
                if ($isFile) {

                    ...

                    // strip tags from data
                    while ($buffer = strip_tags($ioAdapter->streamRead())) {
                        print $buffer;
                    }

                    ...

                } else {
                    $this->getResponse()->setBody($content);
                }
            }
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

as you can see, `strip_tags` is being used to strip the HTML tags before assigning into the buffer variable.

Hope it will help.